# How do I set compile options in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to compile my c# application with D3D_DEBUG_INFO in order to enable enhanced debugging with Direct3D. Where do I place the above option in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express?

Comment: That directive only makes sense to a C++ compiler, you'll have to rebuild whatever DirectX wrapper class library you use.  Since that library probably isn't C++ based, you're stuck and can't use this feature.

Comment: That explains the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Project | Options 
The build section allow you to specify compiler directives.

Comment: Do you mean Project | Properties | Build? I only have available a text field for conditional compilation symbols...

Comment: That is the place to put it.